# Nginx exact match root

Tags: nginx

I have simple url shortener and nginx configuration like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend:5000;
    }
    location /short {
        rewrite /short/(.*) /url/short/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend:5000;
    }
}
```

So my endpoint for redirection is http://myaddr/short/id_of_page
I would like to change it to http://myaddr/id_of_page
I tried something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location = / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend:5000;
    }
    location / {
        rewrite /(.*) /url/short/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend:5000;
    }
}
```

However with this configuration it doesn't catch main page anymore. When I go to http://myaddr/ it is sent to backend for some reason. It seems that exact matching doesn't work.
Why is it happening and how can I debug it?

Comment: I think i know what is going on, but I don't know how to fix it.
location = / catches request and then location / catches it also and in the effect request is going to http://backend:5000//url/short/index.html

For example when I add return 200 in the end of location = / block browser get respnose 200, but with no content :(

Comment: Your original `location /` block was handling more than just `/`. It was also handling `/index.html` and all of the js/css/image files loaded by it. If you want to shorten your short URL, you will need a pattern that uniquely identifies "id_of_page". For example, always numeric, always five characters, no dots.

Comment: You're right. My configuration is bad.
But as far as I understand it shouldn't catch / because it was caught by exact location = /.
Can You explain me what is going on that, / is rewriten to http://backend:5000/url/short/index.html ?

Comment: Your `try_files` statement is rewriting `/` to `/index.html`. Nginx then looks for a `location` to process the rewritten URL, which is `location /`, where it is rewritten a second time to `/url/short/index.html`.

Comment: Is it possible to tell nginx in the end of block "location = / {" to return data to client instead of looking for next matching location block?

Comment: Yes. Change it to `try_files /index.html =404;` - but it still cannot load any resource files.